# SQLite Slow Single Insertion

Tags: android, sql, database

I have e following codes to add a single entry into the database. However it takes more then 5 sec for the insertion to complete. I have tried using transaction as well and the performance is marginally better. Is there a way to speed up the insertion time ?

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("name", username); 

    db.beginTransaction();
    Log.e(TAG,"START");
    // slow insertion
    db.insert("user", null, values);
    Log.e(TAG,"END");       
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();

    db.close();
```

The 5 sec i observed is from the logcat ouput.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you connecting to the SQLite database over a 300 baud modem?  I still don't think it would take 5 minutes.  Is your hard drive failing?  Do other queries succeed?  What do the successful queries look like?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-sqlite

Comment: @RobertHarvey It is not taking 5 min, it is 5 seconds. You read it wrong I think

Comment: Hi , I am running it on an android device. The insertion is successful but it just takes approx 5 seconds. The insertion occurs only when a new user account is created.  Therefore i am not doing bulk insertion.

Comment: When are you opening the database for use? I suggest you should open it in "onResume".

Comment: Do you have any complex triggers or indexes in your table? Is this a table or a view?

Comment: @cha Just a simple table for storing index , username and password.

Comment: @arjun.9990 Currently my program only have a login screen. I am opening the database in onCreate